# J2000 to current ECI transformation matrix

Tags: orbital-mechanics, earth, rotation, frames, eci

I want to find the transformation matrix that converts an ECI frame at some time 't' (lets say t = 1st January 2020) to J2000 ECI frame (that is ECI frame at noon of 1st January 2000). From what I understand, Axial Precession and Nutation will contribute significantly to the desired Transformation Matrix which will be used to convert the position and velocity vectors of a satellite from current ECI frame to J2000 frame.